# Casting shadows on baked objects

Tags: game-engine

I have a scene with objects and lighting, and all the objects have textures/shadows/etc... baked via cycles. For example, the ground plane texture:

[image]

Now I can set all the objects with their baked textures as shadeless and they look fine.

[image]

But I can't get the player object to cast shadows (using the same spot light).

[image]

I understand shadeless essentially turns off shadows, but **I need some way to turn off all shadows except shadows emitted by the player object. Is there a way to do that?** I am trying to achieve real time shadows from a player in a baked environment. Seems like it should be possible?

**I've tried** a ton of the checkboxes and sliders in the materials panel (like `Shadows Only` and `Alpha Blend`) but to no avail.

Comment: Okay, in the opengl, turn OFF shadeless. Then, use the "emit" field or texture plug in slot to apply your texture. Lets see what happens then!

Comment: Could you post a .blend file for us to test with (texture packed in), it helps us to figure out a solution.

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/33423

Answer (score 2):

objects that needs to receive shadows (ground or other objects) can't be shadeless. They need a material with shadow/receive (and/or receive transparent) box checked.
Objects with baked shadows (monkey and icosphere) can have their cast, cast only, cast buffer shadows and cast approximative boxes unchecked. They won't cast shadows on the player (or anything) but it's not a real problem i guess.

[image]